# Spring Boot enable gzip for all mime types

Tags: spring, spring-boot, version, gzip, mime-types

In my Spring Boot application I'm using mime types with versions to determine which content to return e.g. `application/vnd.blah.v2.0.3+json`. The supported versions can vary.

I'm trying to add GZIP compression as stated [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html#how-to-enable-http-response-compression), but the problem is that I have to set all the mime types I want to use for compression. There is no wildcard.

How can I add dynamic mime types for GZIP compression in a Spring Boot application?

Answer (score 1):

Spring will match mime-types that start with what you define.  So if you add: `application/vnd` to your mime-types it will match both: `application/vnd.blah.v2.0.3+json` and `application/vnd.blah.v3.0.0+json`